# How to position a widget relative to another widget?

Tags: flutter, flutter-responsive-layout

Hi I have a circular container and I have to place smaller circular containers at 30 degrees apart on the bigger container (total 12 smaller circles). The smaller circular container center points should always on the circumference of the bigger circle and equally spaced. How can I achieve this in flutter. The smaller circle should always be on the bigger circle even if the bigger circle is scaled (responsive layout) How can I achieve this in flutter UI? Thanks.

Smaller circles on the large circle in flutter UI

Comment: you can use `CustomPainter`, or for simple solution, try to use `Transform` widget

Comment: You could use a Stack and have your large circle and all the smaller ones as children of the Stack.  But wrap each child with a Positioned widget specifying the necessary left and top.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the problem is that I draw the big circle after a fractionally sized box for responsive layout. So when big circle position changes the small circle also needs to change accordingly.

Comment: why don't you use `FittedBox` instead? https://youtu.be/T4Uehk3_wlY

Comment: Fitted box would not work in my case. The smaller circles should always be on the larger circle circumference equally spaced even with scaling.

Comment: and this is exactly what `FittedBox` is doing - simply pass s `Stack` with large circle and multiple small circles